# Yii2 - Log files (app.log) and how to access them?

Tags: file, parsing, logging, methods, yii2

I have a question about logs in Yii2. I want to 
1.) Access log file (both basic/advanced application) 
2.) Parse them using by using regular expressions (separate each part of the log, i partly know, how to do it) 
3.) Display them by using widget (in widget i want to specify, what i want 2 show ) 
Right now, i am struggling, which method to use, when i want to handle those logs. I know they are in : `app\frontend|backend|console\runtime\logs\app.log`, but since i am still Yii2 newbie, i don`t really know, how to perform actions like that. Every answer will be appreciated ! Thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can have logs where ever you want with yii2.

You can define your own logs in the config file depending of the application setup you are using.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-log-target.html

Check the config file under the web section and you will see something like that:

```
    // Logging
    'log' => [
        'targets' => [
            // writes to php-fpm output stream
            [
                'class' => 'codemix\streamlog\Target',
                'url' => 'php://stdout',
                'levels' => ['info', 'trace'],
                'logVars' => [],
                'enabled' => YII_DEBUG,
            ],
```

You can add new ragets like that:

```
                [
                'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                'levels' => ['info', 'trace', 'error', 'warning'],
                'categories' => ['mycategory'],
                'logVars' => [],
                'logFile' => '@runtime/logs/myfolder/myfile.log',
            ],
```

To add lines to this logs you will use something like that:

```
\Yii::info("hi there", 'mycategory');
```

About how to get this path within your code it is as simple as creating an alias in your config file:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-aliases.html

```
Yii::setAlias('@runtime', dirname(__DIR__) . '/../../runtime/logs/myfolder');
```

The rest it is mainly php functions like read the file

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_open.asp

then search about models, passing data from the controller to the view, etc

Comment: Thank you ! Your answer was very helpful !

Comment: can you please check it as valid answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Can you define better what you mean handle? Like open-ecommerce.org has pointed out you have have different targets for your log files. By default it writes to a file, however there are many more targets and they can also be combined. For example you can set up a file log target for regular logs, but when exceptions happen you can send the details on email (and on the file too) to see them faster (or slower :)).

Some options are:
 1. File, just like you said
 2. DB, depending on your configuration the DB target might be faster than your File target. Remember that all logging has a resource cost.
 3. Syslog, quite good if you need to integrate with some enterprise logging solution
 4. Email, send emails when things happen, email has it's good and it's bad parts
others that I have not worked with yet.

If you need to parse the logs I would probably go with the DB option.

Comment: accept one answer please, either this one or the one from open-ecommerce.org